# JSF Dabatabase connection

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to set up a connection to a database using JSF. I am using NetBeansIDE 8.0.2. The database is setup and when I first tested  the connection at database setup it connected fine. I also ran a query through NetBean to view all the tables in the database and it returned results without any issues. When I try to run the project it returns an error that says, Table/view 'ADDRESSES' does not exist. I have tried running the query in multiple ways, but no luck. Any ideas? I tried posting an image of my database, but I wasn't allowed to. Basically I have my database name, which is addressbook, default schema APP, and then my table addresses.

```
package addressbook;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;


@ManagedBean(name="addressBean")
@RequestScoped

public class AddressBean {
    private String lastName;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;

@Resource(name="jdbc/addressbook")
DataSource datasource;

private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public ResultSet getAddresses() throws SQLException
{
    if(datasource == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain datasource");

    Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();

    if(connection == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");

    try{

        PreparedStatement getAddresses = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CITY, STREET, STATE, ZIP " 
                + "FROM addresses ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME"); 

        CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowSet.populate(getAddresses.executeQuery());
        return rowSet;
    }finally{
        connection.close();
    }

}

public String save() throws SQLException
{
    if (datasource == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");

    Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();

    if(connection == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to Datasource");

    try{

        PreparedStatement addEntry = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ADDRESSES" + "(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,STREET,CITY,STATE,ZIP" 
        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?");
        addEntry.setString(1, getFirstName());
        addEntry.setString(2, getLastName());
        addEntry.setString(3, getStreet());
        addEntry.setString(4, getCity());
        addEntry.setString(5, getState());
        addEntry.setString(6, getZipCode());

        addEntry.executeUpdate();
        return "index";
    }finally
    {
        connection.close();
    }
}

}



<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Address Book</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Address Book</h1>
        <h:form>
            <p><h:commandButton value="Add Entry" action="addentry"/></p>

        </h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{addressBean.addresses}" var="address"
                     rowClasses="oddRows,evenRows" headerClass="header"
                     styleClass="table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                #{address.FIRSTNAME}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
                #{address.LASTNAME}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Street</f:facet>
                #{address.STREET}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">CITY</f:facet>
                #{address.CITY}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">STATE</f:facet>
                #{address.STATE}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Zip Code</f:facet>
                #{address.ZIPCODE}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, the problem is the query/database, not JSF

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the problem, but I am not positive why. I have recreated the database several times.